Using SQL alias in connection string
I have set up a local alias to a SQL Server instance.
sqldev -> myserver/MSSQLSERVERDEV

I am wondering if it is possible to use that alias name in my connection string (example shown below):
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OpenSqlConnection();
    Console.Read();
}

private static void OpenSqlConnection()
{
    try
    {
       string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
       {
           connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
           connection.Open();

           Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
           Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}", connection.ConnectionString);
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}

static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return "Data Source=sqldev;Initial Catalog=Data;" +
           "Integrated Security=true;";
}

I can connect to the server using the alias in SSMS, and connect in C# using the full instance name, but when I try to connect in C# using the alias, I get the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Is using an alias in the SQL Server connection string possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14945 perhaps? It seems connecting to alias was deprecated in .net-core

@siggemannen Ah yea looks like you are right. This library available in nuget seems to do the trick though. https://github.com/droyad/SqlAlias

Yeah, i wouldn't use sql alias for modern work though, it's mostly to hack around old clients having hard coded names when you move sql servers

It seems if you use microsoft.sqlclient you can use aliases as before :) System.Data.SQLClient is deprecated
